# What's the difference between a buy vs an acquisition, and a sale vs a disposition?

Tags: stocks, terminology, insider-trading

The image below shows the recent insider transactions in Chipotle Mexican Grill, Inc. stock (NYSE: CMG).

- What is the difference between a "buy" and an "acquisition"?
- What is the difference between a "sell" and a "disposition"?

[image: Table of insider transactions]

Source: https://ir.chipotle.com/insider-transactions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You buy/sell shares when you exchange money for shares and vice versa.

You can also acquire/dispose shares through gifts, option exercises, margin calls, etc.

Comment: Okay, I get it now. Regarding the Chief Restaurant Officer's "sell" and  "disposition" on 2021-04-12: He exercised his stock appreciation rights and got to buy 2826 shares at $582.77. He disposed of 1063 shares at $1550 per share to "pay" for those 2826 shares. He then sold the remaining 1763 shares at $1559.84 per share. Reference: [Form 4](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1058090/000112760221013712/xslF345X03/form4.xml).